# Removing a letter from a string in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have this string

> Alphabet = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

and i want to let the user input a particular word to remove its letters from the alphabet; but once i get the input, i don't know how to really delete the letter from the string so that its size will minimize by one. I have written the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

Alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
echo -n "Please enter your key: "
read -e KEY

Asize=`expr ${#Alphabet} - 1`
Ksize=`expr ${#KEY} - 1`

kcount=0

#A loop to go through the key characters
while [ $kcount -le $Ksize ]
    do
    D=${KEY:$kcount:1}

    Acount=0
#A loop to go through the alphabet characters to look for the current key letter to delete it
    while [ $Acount -le $Asize ]
    do
        if [ "${KEY:$kcount:1}" == "${Alphabet:$Acount:1}" ];

        then
            **REMOVING PART**
            break
        else
            Acount=$[$Acount+1]
```

If someone knows how i can do it I would really appreciate his help.
Thank you. An example is shown:

> input: CZB
>   Output:
>
> Kcount = 0 :ABDFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>
> Kcount = 1 :ABDFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
>
> Kcount = 2 :ADFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXY

Comment: `$[...]` is obsolete, as is `expr` (for arithmetic). Use the standard `$(( ... ))` notation instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ foo="bar"
$ echo "${foo/a/}"
br
```

[Parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

Comment: Actually this code just shows the string excluding the input character, but it doesn't remove it. for example if i execute it later for the "r" letter it will output: "ba".. so the letter "a" was not removed. but thanks anyway for answering.

Comment: Did you try assigning the result back into the variable?

Comment: Note: The second `/` is optional

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tr` utility:

```
SYNOPSIS
     tr [-Ccu] -d string1
     …

DESCRIPTION
     The tr utility copies the standard input to the standard output with sub-
     stitution or deletion of selected characters.
     …

     -d      Delete characters in string1 from the input.
```

Therefore

```
#!/bin/bash
Alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
echo -n "Please enter your key: "
read -e KEY
echo "$Alphabet" | tr -d "$KEY"
```

produces the output `ADFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXY` if you type `CBZ` at the prompt.